# verify or not the column in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to verify 2 columns but sometimes the second one will be empty
then i need to verify the second column just if it's not empty otherwise it will just verify the first one

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE column1 = $_GET['id'] 
and column2 IS NOT NULL = $_GET['id']
```

Comment: Are you saying the one or the other columns might be NULL and whichever is NOT NULL is the one you need the data from?

Comment: Do you want resluts that have col2 as NOT NULL or col2 = $_GET['id']? You can't apply both those conditions in a single statment like that. (col2 = $_GET['id'] will automatically filter out NULLS)

Comment: the second column needs to be verified just if it's not null otherwise it must be ignored @Declan_K

Comment: @EddieD. I have no idea what your comment means

Comment: it would be like this `if(column1 == $id and !empty($column2) == $id)` but in SQL @Declan_K

Comment: In that case `column1 = $_GET['id'] 
and column2 = $_GET['id']` will work as that automatically excludes NULLS

Comment: not exactly.. because if column2 is empty it would be like this `if($column1 == $id)` the second one should be ignored @Declan_K

Comment: Then Gordon's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the logic you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column1 = $_GET['id'] and
      (column2 IS NULL or column2 = $_GET['id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(column1 IS NULL, column2, column1)
FROM table 
WHERE column1 = $_GET['id'] OR column2 = $_GET['id']
```